# Unable to push to git Repository. It hangs after "Writing Objects: 100%"

Tags: git, cygwin, git-pull, git-push, git-daemon

I am running git daemon with the following command.

```
c:\cygwin\bin\git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=/cygdrive/S --export-all --verbose --enable=receive-pack
```

I am able to clone and pull updates but when I try to push I get

```
$ git push origin master

Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6)
```

, then it hangs

I am currently using git version 1.7.0.4

Comment: I'm seeing the same with git v1.7.2.3 on cygwin as server and msysGit v1.7.3.2 as client.

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Same. Someone here with solution?

Comment: I've got a very similar problem, but instead of hanging it gets to the next line (something like `Total 133 (delta 59) reused 80 (delta 33)` ) and then quits. Every time it does the same thing instead of finally reaching `Everything up-to-date` like in other *remotes*. So sad there's not even a clue here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem (Ubunut as git server 1.7.0.4, Windows Msysgit is git client 1.7.0.2).
While it is ok if I use ubuntu git client.

I updated the client to 1.7.1.0, it doesn't help

I use git-daemon to manage the repo (enable receive-back server), and it is a problem. (msysgit with gitdaemon)

When I switch to gitolite, the problem disappear.

Suggest to use git-daemon for read-only

Comment: What SSH client are you using?
Have you got Cygwin installed alongside with Msysgit?

Comment: I use openssh which is in the package from msysgit (openssh_4.6p1).

And I didn't install cygwin.

Comment: btw: how can I check which ssh is used in git, since I switched to putty (plink), it is the same error

Comment: I'm using putty on the client. I have cygwin installed on the server where I run git daemon. From the bash on the client I type: git push git://<path to the repo> master

Answer (score 1):

I had the same (similar?) problem with cygwin git. After one cygwin's update it stopped working properly with remote git repos, both on linux and cygwin.

At first it looked random and was hard to identify. Some commands worked, some failed. It looks like it was connected to the size of data being transferred.

I believe it's a client-side problem with SSH in cygwin as other git clients can connect normally. For me solution was to install msysgit and choose at install its own SSH client, not cygwin's. Putty should work as well, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with server Ubuntu git daemon 1.7.3.2 and client Windows Msysgit 1.7.4.  Downgraded Msysgit to 1.6.5.1 and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Also wasted whole day trying to get this work.
Just stucked with updating 100%
At the end it was the mysgit 1.6.5.1 what made it work. Also if that does not work try in remote linux the command 
git config --bool core.bare true 
when inside your repo folder